# Can I use Git to backup all my server changes?

Tags: backup, git

I want to use Git to monitor all the changes I make to my Ubuntu server. If I rollback changes, can I run into trouble when I rollback changes?

Comment: You are asking us to guess future events ?

Comment: Want to know if I need to exclude certain files/folders from being tracked. I've zero experience with using Git for an OS.

Comment: I understand Git is not an OS. I use it daily to manage my web projects. It occurred to me that I could use Git also to track all of the server changes and make submodules from the different websites hosted on it. It's easy to make commits in the CLI after making some server changes and push it to different repo as backup. If there's a bug I could quickly diff the changes, rollback if I need to or make a new feature branch before trying out new stuff. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's easier with Git to go back in time then most of the backup solutions I know, and Git is pretty light weight and easy to use from the CLI. Is it such a weird idea to use Git as a backup solution for the OS? To get back to my question, I need to know if there are any folders I need to exclude from tracking. Are there cached files or tmp files that get generated alot so can be excluded from tracking?

Comment: Take a look at this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR It is for TAR, but similar to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tangential answer to your question is around managing server configuration rather than the entire server's state itself.

Have a look at using [Puppet](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/puppet.html); Puppet lets you define the state of your machine in terms of configuration, setup, applications, etc.  For example, you can specify things like

- Create a folder at /etc/xyz
- Ensure that the file /opt/java has these permissions
- Ensure that user 'jill' exists with this SSH key
- Ensure that these PPAs are always enabled

The files in which you declare the above configuration are called "Puppet manifests" and what you can do is use git to put those manifests into a repository on a remote git server.  This means you can rerun the Puppet manifests on a fresh install of Ubuntu or undo changes by going back a commit in git.

Comment: Ah great thanks! Never heard of 'Puppet' but I'm reading up on it, this I can use.